# Unable to remove hover from tr element on material design lite

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to remove the background color of a tr element on a table with Material Design Lite.

I'm using Sass.

This is the code causing the effect:

```
.mdl-data-table tbody tr:hover {
background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

This is the code I'm using with no positive results:

```
.mdl-data-table tbody tr:hover{
  tr:hover .no-hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  }
}
```

What am I missing to achieve the behavior I require?

Comment: You're trying to change the background colour from white to white with no effect? Maybe try a different colour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're targetting:

```
tr:hover .no-hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

That's looking for a table row with a **child** with the class `no-hover` (presumably the table cell). The background colour is actually being applied to the row itself.

I believe what you're looking for instead is:

```
tr.no-hover:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Which targets a **row** with the class `no-hover`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved a little bit different with same result:

```
.no-hover tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

and put the class 'no-hover' in the table tag.